# Django Vuejs -- Using Axios - Issue in redering Data

Tags: django, vue.js, axios

I am trying to use VueJs inside my Django Framework ( Django as Backend) and Vuejs as Front-End. However, I am very new with axios, which I found more easier to use with VueJS Front-End. On integrating all togetherr, I didn't see anything coming up but I can see that my code is loop through the data using vueJS Developer Tools.

index.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The greatest news app ever</title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="app">
        <template v-for="post in posts">
          <p> Hello - {{ post.title }}</p>
        </template>

    </div>

     <script src="{% static 'vue/vue.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
   <script src="{% static 'vue/app.js' %}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {

    posts: []
  },



  methods:{
    getPost: function(){
      var self = this;
      let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allpost/";
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        this.posts = response.data
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getPost();
  }

});
```

[The Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QS7Y.png)

Comment: I think what you want to do is put your HTML into a Vue component's template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ post.title }}` has been the problem rendering the Data into Django Page, because Django also make use of this `{{ }}`. However, in a situation where someone is rendering the page with VueJS Server is doesn't apply. then, remember to add this:

`delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],`

```
   <li v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id">
      [[ post.title ]] <br/>
      [[ post.body ]]
      <hr/>
    <li>

new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],

  el: '#app',
  data: {

    posts: []
  },



  methods:{
    getPost: function(){
      var self = this;
      let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allpost/";
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        this.posts = response.data
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getPost();
  }

});
```